# Using Bisection Search on Lowest Payments on Credit Card debt and

Tags: python, bisection

My code:

```
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0 
low = balance/12 
high = (balance*(1+monthlyInterestRate)**12)/12 
guess = (low+high)/2 
unpaidBalance = balance 
month = 1

while True:
    unpaidBalance= unpaidBalance-guess 
        while month < 13:
            if unpaidBalance <= -0.1:
                low = guess
                month += 1
            elif unpaidBalance >= 0.1:
                high = guess
                month += 1
            else:
                break
            guess = (low + high)/2 
print "Lowest Payment: " + str(round(guess, 2))
```

When I test it it gets stuck at the line "while month < 13:"

Why does it do this and how do I fix it?

Comment: what does it means for you that it gets stuck? ...

Comment: It loops at that line.

Comment: Search 'MITx' on stackoverflow to find other people with similar homework problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break at each loop of inner while, you remains less than 13.

And this goes on and on since you proceed `While True` and do not update your `guess`.

I fear you are facing infinite looping there.

Your `break` statement breaks the closest loop, that is the `While month < 13` loop. The next line is not read. `guess`is not updated. The `while True` is not broken.

Maybe you wanted to say

```
while month < 13:
   unpaidBalance= unpaidBalance-guess 
   if unpaidBalance <= -0.1:
         low = guess
   elif unpaidBalance >= 0.1:
         high = guess
   month += 1
   guess = (low + high)/2
```

Comment: I just copied over the code (^^) to try it out, but that is still looping at the same line...???

Comment: because you always fall in your `else` case. Month is not incremented, you remain below 13. Then, you should rework algorithm.

Comment: I'm still so confused! What am I supposed to do exactly?

Comment: try with my last update, then month is ALWAYS incremented and it should work. BUT it all depends of what you want in the end.

Comment: Here's a test case: annualInterestRate = 0.18 and balance = 999999, result should be 90325.07.

Comment: is that yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820003/bisection-search?rq=1 ?

Comment: No, it's not mine but it's the same problem. Thanks for all your help though! ~{^U^}~

Answer (score 1):

here you are

No is the best solution, but it works

```
monthlyPaymentRate = (balance*annualInterestRate/12)/((1-(1+annualInterestRate/12)**-12))

interest = monthlyPaymentRate * (annualInterestRate/12)

#print (monthlyPaymentRate)
#print (interest)
monthlyPaymentRate = (monthlyPaymentRate - interest) +1
#print (monthlyPaymentRate)
balanceInit = balance

epsilon = 0.01
low = monthlyPaymentRate
while low*12 - balance > epsilon:
    balances = balanceInit
    for i in range(12):
                 minpay =  monthlyPaymentRate
                 unpaybal = balances - minpay
                 interest = (annualInterestRate /12) * unpaybal
                  smontfinal =  unpaybal + interest
                  balances = smontfinal
                 #print('Remaining balance: ' ,round(balances,2) )
                 if balances <0:
                     low = -1
                     break
    if balances < 0 :
        low = -1
    else:
        monthlyPaymentRate =monthlyPaymentRate + 0.001 

print('Lowest Payment:' ,round(monthlyPaymentRate,2) )
```